# check if a boost point_xy is initialized or not?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I defined a typedef and:

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> boost2dPoint;
boost2dPoint min_p;
//.
//.(under a condition: min_p will be initialized)
//.
for(Region::Iterator itv = s.beginVer(); itv != s.endVer(); ++itv )
{
  Region::Point v_point = (*itv).pnt();
  if( (v_point(0) == min_p.x()) && (v_point(1) == min_p.y()) )
  {
     return *itv;
  }
}
```

I received a warning

```
‘min_p’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

how can I check if min_p is initialized or not??

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, at least not with that object alone. Uninitialized data is not specially marked, it just doesn't have a specified value. You could have a `bool` flag that's initially set to `false` and set it to `true` when `min_p` is initialized, although if you're going that route, I'd suggest using `boost::optional`:

```
// this is default-initialized to know that its
// data part (a boost2dpoint) is uninitialized
boost::optional<boost2dpoint> min_p; 

// initialize later
if(some_condition()) {
  min_p = boost2dpoint(foo, bar);
}

// use still later:

// Check if min_p has associated data. 
if(min_p) {
  for(Region::Iterator itv = s.beginVer(); itv != s.endVer(); ++itv )
  {
    Region::Point v_point = (*itv).pnt();

                          // +-- note: -> instead of . here. boost::optional is
                          // v                  designed to look like a pointer.        
    if( (v_point(0) == min_p->x()) && (v_point(1) == min_p->y()) )
    {
      return *itv;
    }
  }
}
```

I'll leave a link to [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), which is not terribly long.

Comment: Thanks, even though I use if(min_p.is_initialized()) {...}; I still receive the ‘*((void*)& min_p +8)’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]

Comment: The warning is spurious. It is odd that you get it, though; this warning has been fixed ages ago. Are you using a very old version of gcc or boost?

Comment: boost 1.56, gcc 4.7.2

Comment: Strange. I just tried it with gcc 4.7.4 and boost 1.55 (with -Wall -Wextra -pedantic, and explicitly with -Wmaybe-uninitialized), and I don't get any warnings. Are you sure you're not using `*min_p` somewhere outside the checked block?

Answer (score 0):

You will get this warning if you try to use a variable that has any chance of being uninitialized.  You need to provide an initialization for each path.  Either provide a default initialization when you declare the variable, or provide a value in the `else` case of your condition.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am wondering if there is any embedded function in boost for the null object.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a runtime condition.

I't s static analysis (compiletime) daignostic.

Just initialize your data.

```
boost2dPoint min_p {};
```

or

```
boost2dPoint min_p (0,0);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for the second suggestion: what a bout there is a v_point(0,0); then instead of nullentity, it will return wrong result.

Comment: also it should be initialized for boost2dPoint min_p {}; otherwise: error: in C++98 ‘min_p’ must be initialized by constructor, not by ‘{...}’

Comment: What nullentity is this, that you seem to be talking about? Note that `min_p = {}` will work in c++98 (aggregate initialization). I strongly assume that the default point_xy implementation is very much a POD. There'll be no "nullentity".